# Fetch Data From Mysql Table Using WSO2-DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Wso2  DSS Fetch Data From Table

```
Please Help

I have a table named "Address". I want to fetch the all details(all coulmns) from this table using service created through wso2 dss.

I have to get the responce in json format.

I Have tried it ,but not getting the result
```

pls help

Answer (score 0):

You can check the wso2dss documentation on how to [create a DSS](https://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS321/RDBMS+Sample) and how to [return a JSON](https://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS321/JSON+Mapping+Sample) message. If you face any issue, please post the error stack.

WSO2 DSS distribution comes with default RDBMS sample. you can try that too.

Answer (score 0):

As told by ratha, you can try the sample & understand how it is created. or else you post your table schema and anyone can post xml of that service.

For JSON reponse you need not worry much, you just need to pass one "Accept:application/json" header while calling dss service. first try to get output from dss service.

Comment: Thanks For Your Help..Ratha And mihir